# sed pattern matching, stop at first found character

Tags: sed

Take the string  "hello_world 1 2 3"

I want the output to be "hello_world"

My attempt is "s/\(.*\) .*/\1/g"

But I get "hello_world 1 2"

Instead of stopping at the first space after the sequence, it gets the last space on the line.

I want to take any length of characters \(.*\) followed by a space ' ' and remove anything that comes after it .*

How can I do it?

Comment: regarding the problem you faced, `.*` matches the longest match possible while satisfying the whole regex, which in this case will be the character just before the last space character... you can also solve this using `cut -d ' ' -f1` or `sed 's/ .*//'` or `awk '{print $1}'`

Comment: also, priority is left to right, that is why `\(.*\)` matched as much as possible instead of `.*` at the end of the regex

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following.

```
echo "hello_world 1 2 3" | sed 's/\([^ ]*\).*/\1/'
```

***Explanation of above:***

Using `sed`'s capability of storing matched regex into a temp buffer. Which could be later accessed by variables like `1`, `2` and so on(depending upon number of buffers you are mentioning).

In here we are capturing everything till occurrence of first space into 1st temp buffer and then keeping everything as it is `.*`. While substituting we are mentioning `\1` here which means substitute whole line's value with first matched/stored value of 1st temp buffer(which is `hello_world`).

***Why OP's code not working:*** Because OP using `.*` which is a greedy matched regex and capturing all the line in 1st buffer itself that's why when its used `\1` its actually printing whole line there.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\s.*//' file
```

Matches the first white space character and everything thereafter and removes it, leaving whatever is in front of i.e. all non-white space characters.

Same as:

```
sed 's/^(\S+).*/\1/' -E file
```